# To find words (one or more than one consecutive) having first uppercase in capital?

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regular expression in python, which can find words from text having first letter in uppercase, these words can be single one or consecutive ones.

For example, for the sentence

```
Dallas Buyer Club is a great American biographical drama film,co-written by Craig Borten and Melisa Wallack, and Directed by Jean-Marc Vallee.
```

expexted output should be

```
'Dallas Buyer Club', 'American', 'Craig Borten', 'Melisa Wallack', 'Directed', 'Jean-Marc Vallee'
```

I have written a regular expression for this,

```
([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)
```

but output of this is

```
'Dallas Buyer Club', 'Craig Borten, 'Melisa Wallack', 'Jean-Marc Valee'
```

It is only printing consecutive first uppercase words, not single words like

```
'American', 'Directed'
```

also the regular expression,

```
[A-Z][a-z]+
```

printing all words but individually,

```
'Dallas', 'Buyers', 'Club' and so on.
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed up the brackets (and make the regex a bit too complicated. Simply use:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*
```

So here we have a matching part `[A-Za-z]+` and in order to match more groups, we simply use `(...)*` to repeat `...` *zero* or more times. In the `...` we include the separator(s) (here `\s`) and the group again (`[A-Z][a-z]+`).

This will however **not include the hyphen** between `'Jean'` and `'Marc'`. In order to include it as well, we can expand the `\s`:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+)*
```

Depending on some other characters (or sequences of characters) that are allowed, you may have to alter the `[\s-]` part further).

This then generates:

```
>>> rgx = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+)*')
>>> txt = r'Dallas Buyer Club is a great American biographical drama film,co-written by Craig Borten and Melisa Wallack, and Directed by Jean-Marc Vallee.'
>>> rgx.findall(txt)
['Dallas Buyer Club', 'American', 'Craig Borten', 'Melisa Wallack', 'Directed', 'Jean-Marc Vallee']
```

**EDIT**: in case the remaining characters can be uppercase as well, you can use:

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?:[\s-][A-Z][A-Za-z]+)*
```

Note that this will match words with **two or more characters**. In case single word characters should be matched as well, like `'J R R Tolkien'`, then you can write:

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?:[\s-][A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*
```

Comment: thank for your response sir, it is still not giving single uppercase words 'American' and 'Directed' (only consecutive words), i want both

Comment: now it's working, sir if text contain all capital words like HIV or AIDS, then how to write regex in above one, i have written regex as '[A-Z]+[\s-]', how this can be integrated

Comment: Replace `[A-Z][a-z]+` with `[A-Z][A-Za-z]+`. Furthermore this will only match words with **two or more characters**. If you want to match single character words, as well, you should use `[A-Z][A-Za-z]+`.